# permanently modifying RGB gamma table

Tags: macos, swift, core-graphics

The following script sets a custom gamma table for the current display. It works for about a second before the screen resets to its default profile.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import CoreGraphics

var redTable: [CGGammaValue] = [0, 0]
var greenTable: [CGGammaValue] = [1, 0]
var blueTable: [CGGammaValue] = [0, 1]

CGSetDisplayTransferByTable(CGMainDisplayID(), 2, &redTable, &greenTable, &blueTable)

sleep(5)
```

What causes this reset without me calling `CGDisplayRestoreColorSyncSettings()` directly?
How would I go about permanently adjusting the gamma table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it. I was running [flux](https://justgetflux.com) which reconfigured the display profile every second or so. Quitting the app fixed it.

Comment: Wow, I spent a week trying to track this down. Can't believe it, this was incredibly helpful. Thanks! For anyone else who ends up here, I was using the `CGSetDisplayTransferByFormula` API and was also getting the same behavior with f.lux